# how to make pip trust manually added CA

Tags: python, ssl, pip, openssl

I'm trying to install awscli using pip on a machine behind a corporate proxy using Zscaler.
I know the proxy is setting its own SSL/TLS certificate which I've already added through `update-ca-trust` and I believe it's has done it correctly as things like curl or openssl report a successful connection:

Here's curl downloading a file from pythonhosted (I took the path from the verbose output of pip when installing awscli)

```sh
curl https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/23/51/727b969318e41d1fa5483411d33bea612a219a13b4e009b2650951718ddf/awscli-1.22.99-py3-none-any.whl -o test -vvv
...
* Server certificate:
*   subject: CN=*.pythonhosted.org
*   start date: Apr 16 05:23:51 2022 GMT
*   expire date: Apr 30 05:23:51 2022 GMT
*   common name: *.pythonhosted.org
*   issuer: CN="Zscaler Intermediate Root CA (zscaler.net) (t) ",OU=Zscaler Inc.,O=Zscaler Inc.,ST=California,C=US
...
data
...
```

Here's openssl output

```sh
openssl s_client -connect files.pythonhosted.org:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=3 C = US, ST = California, L = San Jose, O = Zscaler Inc., OU = Zscaler Inc., CN = Zscaler Root CA, emailAddress = support@zscaler.com
verify return:1
depth=2 C = US, ST = California, O = Zscaler Inc., OU = Zscaler Inc., CN = Zscaler Intermediate Root CA (zscaler.net), emailAddress = support@zscaler.com
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, ST = California, O = Zscaler Inc., OU = Zscaler Inc., CN = "Zscaler Intermediate Root CA (zscaler.net) (t) "
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = r.shared-319-default.ssl.fastly.net
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/CN=r.shared-319-default.ssl.fastly.net
   i:/C=US/ST=California/O=Zscaler Inc./OU=Zscaler Inc./CN=Zscaler Intermediate Root CA (zscaler.net) (t) 
 1 s:/C=US/ST=California/O=Zscaler Inc./OU=Zscaler Inc./CN=Zscaler Intermediate Root CA (zscaler.net) (t) 
   i:/C=US/ST=California/O=Zscaler Inc./OU=Zscaler Inc./CN=Zscaler Intermediate Root CA (zscaler.net)/emailAddress=support@zscaler.com
 2 s:/C=US/ST=California/O=Zscaler Inc./OU=Zscaler Inc./CN=Zscaler Intermediate Root CA (zscaler.net)/emailAddress=support@zscaler.com
   i:/C=US/ST=California/L=San Jose/O=Zscaler Inc./OU=Zscaler Inc./CN=Zscaler Root CA/emailAddress=support@zscaler.com
...
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    Session-ID: ADE0E7C5AC943FC27E00383810F13A0CE78DF45B268D050A5015E50C1A6F316E
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: CF3552DAAB06FC3C97713DD1D4AE2872317F64C483720CB5ABFDA2C8F0B4FBB37CEB33F26338F1AA5E7F3182A5040480
    Key-Arg   : None
    Krb5 Principal: None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    Start Time: 1650578618
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

I'm trying to avoid using a `trusted-host` or disabling ssl verification.

Is there any way to fix this or troubleshoot this further?

I'm using

```sh
pip 21.3.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
```

Comment: perhaps the main issue is my missunderstanding that pip would use the system CA stores and apparently it is not doing that.
A potential workarround is using "sudo env REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=/etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/openssl/ca-bundle.trust.crt python3 -m pip install pip_system_certs" which installs pip_system_certs and also tells pip to use the ca-bundle specifically. After that, all pip installs should work fine due to pip_system_certs

Comment: in case this helps anybody: https://help.zscaler.com/zia/adding-custom-certificate-application-specific-trusted-store